# Taking value of edittext and putting a decimal point in it

Tags: java, android

All-
I am working on an app in which the user enters the bill cost the tip rate. I know how to take the values of the edittext fields and preform the necessary math on them, but on the tip rate field I have to add a decimal point in front of the entered numbers. So if the user inputs "2" it shows up in the java code as ".2". Is there a way to do this?
Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple -

If you want a dot between the characters, just divide it by 10^(length).
So if the entered string is 2, divide by 10. If its 22, divide by 100.

Other alternative would be -

```
  String value = editText.getText().toString();
if(!value.contains(".")) //Better if you check the value doesn't already have a decimal
    value = "."+value; //This is the string with . in the front
    float tip = Float.parseFloat(value); //Use it for calculations.
```

Comment: How would it look in code if I were to divide the number by 10^(length)?

Comment: In that case, it would be Float.parseFloat(editText.getText().toString()) / (Math.pow(10, editText().getText().toString().length());